# mysql query syntax, get data from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

I got this bookshop website, and I'm trying to generate some statistics about sales. I've got two tables; `books` and `sales_item`. They look like this:

`books`

```
id  title
1   Cats
2   Dogs
3   Frogs
```

and `sales_item`

```
book_id  qty
1        2
2        2
3        4
3        1
2        1
and so on for hundreds of rows
```

So what I'm after is a sql query and a html table that tells me that we've sold 2 Cats, 3 Dogs and 5 Frogs. I want to match `id` from one table with `book_id` from the other and then add all the `qty` for each `title`. I have a feeling that this involves sql JOIN but I'm still not very comfortable with the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b.id, b.title, sum(s.qty) as NumSold 
from books b 
left outer join sales_item s on b.id = s.book_id 
group by b.id, b.title 
order by b.title
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7cc/2/0)

Comment: thanks! but this returns `#1054 - Unknown column 'order_item.qty' in 'field list'`, even when i change `sum(qty)` to `sum(sales_item.qty)`. there is a `qty` in the book table too.

Comment: sorry, i mean i get the unknown column warning after editing to sales_item.qty. using just qty gives me "Column 'qty' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: this works, although there was some other issues with tables i didn't mention in the example above. like filtering only paid orders etc. but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i finally worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(qty), title
from sales_item s
left join books b on s.book_id = b.id
group by s.book_id
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bd6b6/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$query = ("select sum(qty) as 'Quantity', title from books b left join sales_item s on b.id = s.bookid' group by book_id");

$result = mysql_query($query);

//and this would be the code to print the html table

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Pet</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tittle'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Got help from a w3school [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).